# How to result and validate associated data from multiple Table cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Example: 2 tables

**Table 1:**

"Orders"

cells:

```
-id

-etc

-etc
```

**Table 2:**

"Sales_uploads"

cells:

```
-id

-order_id (same data as "id" in Orders table)

-etc

-etc
```

I have created =

```
Order.where(id: Sales_upload.pluck(:order_id))
```

from Googling, but haven't figured out where to go from here.

I have this def in my sales_upload model:

```
def order_sales_relationship
    Order.where(id: Sales_upload.pluck(:order_id)) 
end
```

Then in the views I have: (a portion of views)

```
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="center"><%= order.buyer.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price) %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= order.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></td>

        <td class="center">
          <div class="field">


            <% if @order_sales_relationship = true %>
            <%= link_to '/sales' %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path( order, @order ), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
```

When i use this, '/sales' appears in the upload section of the table even if nothing has been uploaded. I believe the model is incorrect and may jst be validating if the cells exist, but not validating if they also match. How would i validate the matching as wlel (if this is even true)

The goal is to display an upload link ONLY if the upload hasn't happened yet. If it has, I want only an update/edit link (which is '/sales' atm as a placer, that's a whole other issue).

Comment: btw `<% if @order_sales_relationship = true %>` should be `<% if @order_sales_relationship == true %>` also where is `@order_sales_relationship`?

Comment: When I do ==, the /sales doesn't appear so i thought it was only 1 =

In my OrdersController, I have a sales method which displays the info on the /sales page.  If so, how would i implement the @ order_sales_relationship within that method, or do i even need to? It can just be separate.  I'm new to coding btw so i know this may be obvious but just making sure!

Comment: check my answer

Comment: As for the "==" ... when i try it, I tested it by creating a new order and uploading a new file, but the Upload button still appears.

I edited it, my apologese

Answer (score 0):

ok from what I'm understanding, please correct me

change

```
def order_sales_relationship
  Order.where(id: Sales_upload.pluck(:order_id)) 
end
```

to

```
def order_sales_relationship
  @order_sales = Order.where(id: Sales_upload.pluck(:order_id)) 
end
```

in view make this changes

```
<% if @order_sales.present? %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(order, @order), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

??? where is @order

Comment: Here's my Git repo: https://github.com/brandnamewater/digitalcommerce - Sorry just going to link that because not sure exactly what you mean.  I have the Orders model doing has_one :sales_upload

Comment: So i just was messing around in the controller and found out i can't even access my sales_upload.rb model.  I get the following error: Unable to autoload constant Sales_upload, expected sales_upload.rb to define it....... so this may be a big part of the issue